# Create users and roles programmatically in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there a way in ActiveMQ Artemis to create users and roles dynamically from code or is calling shell command *artemis* or *artemis.cmd* the only way?

Edit: Also, is there a way to list and delete users and roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI commands use the [management API](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#the-management-api) to [add](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#addUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean)), [list](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#listUser(java.lang.String)), [remove](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#removeUser(java.lang.String)), and [reset](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#resetUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean)) users. The management API is accessible in many different ways. For example, if your broker is embedded you can invoke the management API directly. If your broker is remote you could use JMX (either administratively or programmatically, programmatic example [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/standard/jmx)), HTTP (via Jolokia), or management messages (example [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/standard/management)).